# Automation tool to deal with SWT and NatTable

Tags: java, swt, swtbot, nebula

I have a task to find out best automation tool for my desktop based product. When I discussed with developers, they said, the product uses SWT (Standard Widget Toolkit) for GUI development, and used Nuebula Project (NatTable, tableCombo) for tables and combo boxes. So if I get a tool, which will deal with nubula & SWT, my task is almost done. 
Any help here ? Which can be the best tool to deal with these technologies?

What I am used to is selenium for web-based applications. But desktop based applications and using SWT & Nebula is totally new for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [SWTBot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/), [RCPTT](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.rcptt) which claims to support NatTable since 2.1 (although the bugzilla ticket was never closed) and once in a forum [QF-Test](https://www.qfs.de/en/index.html) was mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I am exploring SWTBot & QF-Test. Will have a look at RCPTT as well.

Comment: https://jira4.xored.com/browse/QS-3050?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

"Best" tool here is going to be pretty subjective, but I'll throw out [eggPlant](https://www.testplant.com/eggplant/testing-tools/eggplant-developer/) as a tool that I've heard lots of great things about. I've never used it personally (and have no affiliation with TestPlant), but from conversations that I've had with our testers, they picked it up immediately and found it to be very intuitive. The main advantage here is that it will work on any platform - not just for your use-case of a desktop app that uses SWT. On the other hand, I'm not sure how expensive it is, but your company/group may be able to leverage it across the board, so there are some pros and cons in that regard as well.

Comment: Thanks "avojak" for your help. Gone through eggPlant on internet, seems impressive. If you can comment on one of query from your contacts is, "Is eggPlant useful when AUT has frequently changing UI". From TestPlant website, it says eggPlant uses image recognition based approach, so if UI changes, I guess it will fail.